# How do I get lint-staged working with Husky version 6

Tags: eslint, pre-commit-hook, pre-commit, husky, lint-staged

I try to use Husky's `pre-commit` and `lint-staged`.

Those are installed:

```
"husky": "^5.1.3",
"lint-staged": "^10.5.4",
```

In package.json I have:

```
"scripts": {
    "build": "gatsby build",
    "develop": "gatsby develop",
    "format": "prettier --write \"**/*.{js,jsx,ts,tsx,json,md}\"",
    "start": "npm run develop",
    "serve": "gatsby serve",
    "clean": "gatsby clean",
    "test": "echo \"Write tests! -> https://gatsby.dev/unit-testing\" && exit 1",
    "lint": "eslint --ext .js,.jsx,.ts,.tsx src --color",
    "isready": "npm run format && npm run lint && npm run build"
  },
  "husky": {
    "hooks": {
      "pre-commit": "lint-staged",
      "pre-push": "npm test",
    }
  },
  "lint-staged": {
    "./src/*.{js,jsx,ts,tsx}": [
      "npm run format",
      "npm run lint",
      "git add"
    ]
  },
```

If I run `npm run lint`, currently I have `2 problems (1 error, 1 warning)`. So when I run `git commit`, I don't expect to be able to commit, right? But I can proceed and finish the commit.

What's wrong?

**Update:**

I downgraded husky to `4.3.8`:

```
"husky": "^4.3.8",
"lint-staged": "^10.5.4",
```

Inside `package.json`, in my scripts I have:

```
"prettier": "prettier '**/*.{js,jsx,ts,tsx}' --write",
"lint": "eslint --ext .js,.jsx,.ts,.tsx src --color",
```

And:

```
"husky": {
    "hooks": {
      "pre-commit": "lint-staged"
    }
  },
  "lint-staged": {
    "src/**/*.{ts,tsx,js,jsx}": [
      "npm run prettier",
      "npm run lint",
      "git add"
    ]
  },
```

When I do a commit, Husky is still not fired off. What's wrong?

**Update 2:**
I couldn't get Husky `4` to work so I [upgraded](https://github.com/typicode/husky-4-to-6) to version `6`:

```
npm install husky@6 --save-dev \
  && npx husky-init \
  && npm exec -- github:typicode/husky-4-to-6 --remove-v4-config
```

Now it works fine.

The only thing I can't get to work is lint-staged.

- I added the hook `npx husky add .husky/pre-commit "lint-staged"`

But then I get `.husky/pre-commit: line 4: lint-staged: command not found`? How do I get `lint-staged` working with Husky version 6?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Making `lint-staged` working with Husky version 6 by adding:

```
// .husky/pre-commit
npm run pre-commit
```

and:

```
// package.json
{
  "scripts": {
    "pre-commit": "lint-staged"
  }
}
```

Comment: not working for me
`"scripts": {
    "ng": "ng",
    "start": "ng serve",
    "build": "ng build --prod --aot --buildOptimizer --commonChunk --vendorChunk --optimization --progress",
    "test": "ng test",
    "lint": "ng lint",
    "e2e": "ng e2e",
    "pre-commit": "lint-staged"
  },
  "husky": {
    "hooks": {
      "commit-msg": "commitlint -E HUSKY_GIT_PARAMS",
      "pre-commit": "lint-staged",
      "post-merge": "post-npm-install"
    }
  },
  "lint-staged": {
    "src/**/*.{ts,tsx,md}": [
      "tslint -p tsconfig.json -c tslint.json",
      "git add"
    ]
  }

Answer (score 9):

Based on this [husky github issue](https://github.com/typicode/husky/issues/949#issuecomment-823807906), just do these steps to make it work(we did it and it is working fine):

1. `npx husky-init`
2. `yarn`
3. `npx husky add .husky/commit-msg 'npx --no-install commitlint --edit "$1"'`
4. `yarn add @commitlint/config-conventional @commitlint/cli --dev`

`.commitlintrc.json`:

```json
{
  "extends": ["@commitlint/config-conventional"]
}
```

`.lintstagedrc`:

```json
{
  "src/**/*.+(js|json|ts|tsx)": [
    "eslint"
  ],
  "src/**/*.{js,jsx,ts,tsx,json,css,scss,md}": [
    "prettier --write"
  ]
}
```

`.husky/pre-commit`:

```
#!/bin/sh
. "$(dirname "$0")/_/husky.sh"

yarn pre-commit-lint
```

Finally, add `pre-commit-lint` script to `package.json`:

```json
{
  "name": "pwa-react-scaffold",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "author": "SeyyedMahdi Hassanpour <SeyyedKhandon@gmail.com>",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "react-scripts start",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "test": "react-scripts test",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject",
    "analyze": "yarn build && source-map-explorer 'build/static/js/*.js'",
    "lint": "eslint --ignore-path .gitignore --ext .js,.ts,.tsx .",
    "check-types": "tsc",
    "prettier": "prettier --ignore-path .gitignore \"src/**/*.+(js|jsx|json|ts|tsx)\"",
    "format": "yarn prettier --write",
    "check-format": "yarn prettier --list-different",
    "validate": "npm-run-all --parallel check-types check-format lint build",
    "prepare": "husky install",
    "pre-commit-lint": "yarn check-types && yarn lint-staged"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@testing-library/jest-dom": "^5.11.4",
    "@testing-library/react": "^11.1.0",
    "@testing-library/user-event": "^12.1.10",
    "@types/jest": "^26.0.15",
    "@types/node": "^12.0.0",
    "@types/react": "^16.9.53",
    "@types/react-dom": "^16.9.8",
    "node-sass": "^5.0.0",
    "react": "^17.0.2",
    "react-dom": "^17.0.2",
    "react-scripts": "4.0.3",
    "source-map-explorer": "^2.5.2",
    "typescript": "^4.0.3",
    "web-vitals": "^0.2.4",
    "workbox-background-sync": "^5.1.3",
    "workbox-broadcast-update": "^5.1.3",
    "workbox-cacheable-response": "^5.1.3",
    "workbox-core": "^5.1.3",
    "workbox-expiration": "^5.1.3",
    "workbox-google-analytics": "^5.1.3",
    "workbox-navigation-preload": "^5.1.3",
    "workbox-precaching": "^5.1.3",
    "workbox-range-requests": "^5.1.3",
    "workbox-routing": "^5.1.3",
    "workbox-strategies": "^5.1.3",
    "workbox-streams": "^5.1.3"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@commitlint/cli": "^12.1.1",
    "@commitlint/config-conventional": "^12.1.1",
    "@typescript-eslint/eslint-plugin": "^4.22.0",
    "@typescript-eslint/parser": "^4.22.0",
    "eslint-config-prettier": "^8.2.0",
    "eslint-plugin-jest-dom": "^3.8.0",
    "eslint-plugin-testing-library": "^4.1.0",
    "eslint-plugin-unused-imports": "^1.1.1",
    "husky": "^6.0.0",
    "lint-staged": "^10.5.4",
    "npm-run-all": "^4.1.5",
    "prettier": "^2.2.1"
  }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

@meez As you install **husky@^5.1.3** version, Husky changed the configuration step after 5.0.0.

Configure Husky@^5.0.0:

```
    npm i husky
    npx husky install
    husky install .config/husky
    husky add .config/husky/pre-commit "npm test"
```

Link: https://dev.to/typicode/what-s-new-in-husky-5-32g5

or you can simply degrade your husky version :)

Comment: @meez which version you are use? make sure remove *-lock files before downgrade the version

Comment: I have the same issue, when following the husky 5 setup I end up with `missing script: lint-staged`. Any idea why? @Sandeep?

Comment: have you download **lint-staged** package and had you the entry of script **npm test** in package.json file?

Comment: yeah i had to add `lint-staged` as an npm script in my package.json. but in the end I also needed to adjust the config, because our .git file was not on the same level as the package.json. took me a bit to figure that out. it's working now. thanks

Answer (score 4):

another option: Use npx in the pre-commit config

`.husky/pre-commit`

```
#!/usr/bin/env sh
. "$(dirname -- "$0")/_/husky.sh"

npx lint-staged
```

Answer (score 0):

In my case the issue was not in the lint-staged config, but was caused by WebStorm settings. `Git: Enable staging area` setting was turned off, that's why lint-staged couldn't detect any changed files. Turning the setting back on fixed the issue:

1. Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>A</kbd> (or <kbd>⌘</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>A</kbd>)
2. Type "git staging" and you'll see the option `Git: Enable staging area`
3. Click on the item to enable the feature

See [Webstorm guide](https://www.jetbrains.com/idea/guide/tips/enable-git-staging/)